# spring tool suite quick search syntax?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I want to use the **in** to narrow down the search, What is the syntax in spring tool suite quick search ?

[image: spring tool suite quick seach]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation uses `org.apache.tools.ant.types.selectors.TokenizedPattern` for the path patterns. Example are here:

https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/master/org.eclipse.text.quicksearch.tests/src/org/eclipse/text/quicksearch/tests/ResourceMatcherTest.java